# I want to convert my HTML page to PDF format with keeping CSS style on it

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

I want to convert my HTML page to PDF format with keeping CSS style on it. I'm doing it already but I cannot grab CSS. I'm getting only html without css. Is this possible to do somehow?

Comment: What's the usecase? Show the code you already have now.  If it's just for your own personal use, you could "print as PDF". Otrherwise you could use a library like html2pdf...

Comment: be clear with your question

Comment: I have single page with some buttons, images, headers, colors and so one. I have button download page and I want when click on it to get that page that I can later print with all colors margins and so one...

Comment: basically I want to get my page in PDF or something similar...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at DOMPdf. Its a PHP library for generating PDFs.
https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

There is also a JavaScript library but I guess its not as powerful like the PHP version.
https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

Comment: this javascript I'm using already....it's working fine without css... I will try php version...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exacty what you're attempting to do. But you should look at this tool : [html2print](http://osp.kitchen/tools/html2print/). (on github : [github.com/osp/osp.tools.html2print](https://github.com/osp/osp.tools.html2print))

Comment: this is working fine I'm getting all, but I need to get html content in PDF. So just like this one but in PDF if it's possible...

Comment: what you can read in [the Print section of the readme](https://github.com/osp/osp.tools.html2print#print) doesn't satisfy you ? If not, what more do you want  ?

Comment: When I do that and click on the action button I can print the page and that's fine, but I want to download that page content in pdf format with all css elements ok?